# Is every element of a finite group a product of elements of prime order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This was inspired by my earlier question

[Is every element of a group an element of a Sylow p-subgroup of that group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015702/is-every-element-of-a-group-an-element-of-a-sylow-p-subgroup-of-that-group/2015705#2015705)

which has a negative answer.

Comment: Consider a cyclic group of order $p^2$. Make it prime-power order, and it might be true.

Comment: Aha, how about, 'except if the order of that element is one or zero'? Is this a bit like the Goldbach conjecture? I.e., elements of a cyclic group are products of prime order iff all naturals are the sum of some number of primes.

Comment: The problem in my example are the generators. The elements of order dividing $p$ form a proper subgroup, so no generator can be written as a product of elements of smaller order.

Comment: @DanielFischer Every element of a finite group is certainly a product of elements of prime power since the Sylow subgroups generate the whole group.

Comment: Oh I see - sorry I got muddled between order and an element being a power of a generator.